# Вывод символa по ascii коду

Tags: c, ascii

Нужно вывести символы имея код. Такое почему-то не работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 65;
    printf("%s", (char)a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: верно, строка ведь. Нужно %c использовать

Comment: Можно и строку - при определенных условиях :) См. мой ответ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%c` - выводит одиночный символ.
`%s` - выводит строку, а строка в С должна завершаться нулем.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что строка не только должна завершаться нулем, но и передаваться должен адрес строки, а не само значение как в случае с символом

Comment: @Mike: Поскольку в C по большому счёту нету строк (они _эмулируются_ указателями), то передать _саму строку_, боюсь, невозможно.

Answer (score 3):

В данном предложении

```
printf("%s", (char)a);
```

значение выражения `(char)a` рассматривается как адрес строки, завершаемой 0, так как символ форматирования `%s` используется для вывода строк с завершающим 0.

Для вывода отдельного символа вы можете использовать символ форматирования `%c`. В этом случае нет никакой необходимости использовать приведение типов `(char)a`, так как на самом деле аргумент будет снова преобразован к типу `int`. То есть вы можете просто записать

```
printf( "%c", a );
```

Answer (score 1):

Самом смешное, что при прямом порядке байт (на архитектуре типа x86) можно просто указать `&a` - и этот dirty hack :) сработает. Поскольку int - это все же обычно 4 байта (ну самая малость на 16-битных DOS'ах - 2), а ASCII-код помещается в одном байте, то второй (и последующие) будут нулевыми, так что `&a` по сути получается указателем на строку из одного символа. Так что

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 65;
    printf("%s", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

как ни смешно, сработает - при указанных выше условиях...